# Odoo xpath expression rule

Tags: xpath, odoo

I'm developing a Qweb report in Odoo and I need to use xpath expressions for replacing some content.

This is the main template where is needed to make the replace of the content:

```
<template id="report_saleorder2_template">
        <t t-name="report_saleorder2_template">
            <t t-call="web.external_layout">
             <div class="page">
                <div class="oe_structure" />
                    <div class="row" id="report_data_0">
                        <h1>Annual voluntary contribution to Fecoas - Alcaste school</h1>
//more code
```

This is the other template where I'm tying to use the xpath expression for replacing the content:

```
<template id="report_saleorder3_template">
    <t t-name="report_saleorder3_template">
        <t t-call="custom_v12_reports.report_saleorder2_template" t-lang="doc.partner_id.lang" />
           <xpath expr="//div[@id='report_data_0']/h1[1]" position="replace">
                     <h1>Annual AMPA's member fee Alcaste school</h1>
           </xpath>
       </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

This is not working. Someone knows why?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to inherit the origin template with `inherit_id`. Then you're able to use XPath expressions to change or add new code.

```xml
<template id="report_saleorder3_template" 
        inherit_id="module_name.report_saleorder2_template">
    <xpath expr="//div[@id='report_data_0']/h1[1]" position="replace">
        <h1>Annual AMPA's member fee Alcaste school</h1>
    </xpath>
    <!-- and other XPath expressions -->
</template>
```